# Android - Setting a Background across 4 ImageViews

Tags: java, android, imageview

How can I achieve the effect that 4 Imageviews have one specified part of a background?
I want to get this effect:

[image: WP 8.1 Home]

Is there any way I can do this?
Thanks.

Thanks @ChiefTwoPencil for the Answer! The achieved result:[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Has this been done anywhere in android? I would like to know. Nice question

Comment: Not sure @gurinderhans, if not, I want to be the first :P

Comment: Well I guess you would carefully position your image across four imageviews and only show the different parts of the image. This wont be very portable though.

Comment: Are those tiles moveable? If not, it's just a matter of slicing an image.

Comment: The problem persists, in my app, I need the user to be able to resize the Imageviews and drag them around..

Comment: The main parent could have the image as its background and the image views that show the image would be transparent, others would be what ever they are; right? Add black borders to the image views.

Comment: Chief2Pencils has the correct solution, but if you need to resize the imageViews and drag them around. That should be asked as a separate question since this is a new requirement, and you should attempt to answer and code some of that solution yourself before you re-post that part as a question. We mostly only help the people who are willing to prove to us that they've attempted to solve the problem first with actual code.

Comment: I've got a plan for that :P @StephanBranczyk

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following code...

create xml file res/layout folder and place the following code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/transibg"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/img1"
    android:background="@drawable/transibg"
    android:text="Button2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

create xml file under res/drawable folder and the code and name it as transibg.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

then run the project.I hope this one you want..